# KDE: false detection of "switch to external screen"

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display, kde, kde5

Since KDE display configuration is broken (and by other reasons) it is better to configure displays via xorg.conf. But after that KDE starts to display bogus dialog asking to change display mode. How to disable it completely and tell KDE to not try to reconfigure displays?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the System Settings -> Background Services -> Startup and Shutdown.

I unticked KScreen 2, this stops it from starting automatically.

[image]

Comment: This did the trick for me. Thanks!